# Something wrong with my Latex table, can anybody help me?

Tags: tables

There is something wrong with my Latex table, the first left vertical line is too long. Besides, how could I make the capability in the middle of the column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Concept}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{8cm}<{\centering}|}
\hline
\textbf{Models}& \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}  
\\
\hline 

\multirow{2}{*}{Capability} & CC & Combined capabilities are upper-level capabilities, which can be divided by functional decomposition into simple, lower-level capabilities \\ \cline{2-3}
& SC & Simple Capability is a single capability that the resources have  
\\ 
\hline
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: move `\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}` out of the last row

Answer (score 2):

- Move \label{table:semantic models of OCCR model} out of the last row (as suggested @DavidCarlisle).
- I would use `tabularx` and prescribe its table width to be equal to `\textwidth`.
- At use of `multrow` consider that for number of rows you must actually consider number of text lines in the spanned rows (5 instead of 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Concept}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}
                             |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}
                             |C|}
    \hline
\textbf{Models} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}    \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{Capability} 
                & CC & Combined capabilities are upper-level capabilities, which can be divided by functional decomposition into simple, lower-level capabilities \\ 
    \cline{2-3}
                & SC & Simple Capability is a single capability that the resources have\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may consider to use `tabularray` package. Using it, the table code is shorter, at multi row cell consider number of spanned rows (in contrary as at other tables packages) in have better vertical spacing of cells contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Concept}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={X[l] X[c] X[4,c,m]},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries}
            }

Models  & Symbol    & Description       \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Capability 
        & CC & Combined capabilities are upper-level capabilities, which can be divided by functional decomposition into simple, lower-level capabilities \\
        & SC & Simple Capability is a single capability that the resources have\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `tabularray`, the vertical spacing is also nicer, not squeezed at top and bottom.